# How can I attach a click event to an element added to the DOM by a plugin in Angular 7+?

Tags: angular, events, onclicklistener, dom-events, vmware-clarity

I'm using the VMWareClarity module to add a datagrid to a page. As part of this datagrid, there's a button to open a popup over the grid to select which columns to hide/show. Once the columns are selected, the popup can be closed by clicking the close button.

I need to attach an action to the close button in the popup, but I haven't been able to access the element to click it as it's only rendered in the DOM once I click the Hide/Show columns button. I've tried adding an `elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector` in `ngAfterViewInit`, `changeDetection`, and `@HostListener` but none are able to find the new popup element loaded into the DOM.

Comment: This would be a feature request I believe, we aren't making this event public for you to listen to. What is the event you need to attach and why to this specific button?

Comment: Hi @JeremyWilken, our app is persisting the open/closed grid columns for the user so that they can load the app with their selected hidden/shown columns. I suppose the event is the `clr-dg-column-toggle` popup close button event. Hooking the save action into the close button for the popup made the most sense in this context as it's an actionable confirmation that the popup changes are complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I was able to use a HostListener on the document, then track if the event target `nodeName` was the element I was looking for (as every element has a `nodeName`):

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
onClick(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName === 'CLR-ICON') {
      // Do something
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your parent nodes for your target element? Usually a Pop-up (depends on your UI framework) is created on the hightest DOM Level in the **Body** Tag. Otherwise you still can implement an `Output() EventEmitter` like shown here: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2

Example code for the outputting component:

```
@Output() change = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

Comment: The element does get appended to the `<body>`. I just need to target a button within this popup. The popup element in question is added by the plugin to the DOM after `ngAfterViewInit` and isn't previously referenced in the component so I haven't yet been able to attach an event to the close button to be able to emit the Output.